# During manual calling the destructor occurs the error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c++, oop

I'm beginner with oop and this is my the learning project. The simulator of managing a company. Firstly I'm not sure if my idea is correct. I must to manually call the destructor to keep the right number of hired employees, I guess. If I won't do it then in case if the user does not want to employ the generated guy the constructor will increase `ID` anyway. So if someone has a better idea to solve it I'm open for propositions. My issue is that in line with `delete some_new_employee` the error occurs. I don't understand what it means. I'd like to ask for any explanations.

```
class Employee
{
private:
    static int ID;
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int id;

    Employee::Employee()
    {
        id = ID++;
    }

    Employee::~Employee()
    {
        --id;
    }

    int Number()
    {
        return id;
    }
};

int Employee::ID = 0;

Employee generate_random_employee(Employee obj)
{
    std::vector<std::string> male_names = { "Donald", "Piotr", "James", "Tiny", "Ricky" };
    std::vector<std::string> female_names = { "Diana", "Joelle", "Sue", "Karolina" };
    std::vector<std::string> lastnames = { "Lester", "Pound", "Park", "Ennis", "Duck",
        "Tusk", "Disney", "Jurassic", "Looney-Warde" };

    int sex = (rand() % 2) + 0;

    if (sex == 1)
    {
        obj.name = male_names[(rand() % (male_names.size() - 1)) + 0];
    }
    else
    {
        obj.name = female_names[(rand() % (female_names.size() - 1)) + 0];
    }

    obj.name += " " + lastnames[(rand() % (lastnames.size() - 1)) + 0];
    obj.age = (rand() % 24) + 25;

    return obj;
}

bool are_u_sure()
{
    std::string decision;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Are you sure [Y/N]?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> decision;

        if (decision == "y" || decision == "Y")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (decision == "n" || decision == "N")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unknow option. Try again." << std::endl;
        }
    } while (true);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    std::string option;

    std::cout << "Welcome mrs. manager. What do you want to do today, sir?" << std::endl << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Type .hire to hire a new employee" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> option;

        if(option == ".hire")
        {
            Employee some_new_employee;
            some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(some_new_employee);

            std::cout << "So... do you want to hire a new employee? Let's look at CVs " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "I've got one. What do u think about " << some_new_employee.name << " age " << some_new_employee.age << "?" << std::endl;

            if (are_u_sure())
            {
                employees.push_back(some_new_employee);
            }
            else
            {
                delete some_new_employee;
            }
        }
    } while (option != ".end");
}
```

Comment: You call `delete` on objects allocated with `new`.

Comment: Well... the question is: how should I destroy properly the object which have been created by `Employee some_new_employee`?

Comment: It gets destroyed automatically when the block is exited.  You're not suppsed to manually call the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are to only call `delete` on objects allocated with `new`.

These lines:

```
Employee some_new_employee;
some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(some_new_employee);
```

don't use any pointers (which what `delete` requires), and doesn't allocate using `new` (which is the second thing that is required for `delete` to be used).

The `some_new_employee` is an automatic variable that will get destroyed automatically when the block that it is declared in is exited.  In other words, here:

```
 if(option == ".hire")
 {
    Employee some_new_employee;
    some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(some_new_employee);
    // code
    //...
 }  // <-- some_new_employee gets destroyed here, automatically
```

If the reason why you felt the need to destroy it is because of the usage of `std::vector` in your code block, a `vector` makes *copies* of the object you place in it.  Thus it is safe for `some_new_employee` to be destroyed, since the vector already has stored a copy of it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you properly. Do you want to say that if we'll leave the `if` block without `push_back()` the object, the object will be destroyed itself?

Comment: Yes.  This is a fundamental of C++.  If an automatic variable leaves scope, it is destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'delete some_new_employee' is unnecessary.
Because 'delete' is for a pointer of object.

```
if(option == ".hire")
{
    Employee* temp_some_new_employee = new Employee();
    Employee some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(*temp_some_new_employee);

// ==========something=========

    if (are_u_sure())
    {
        employees.push_back(some_new_employee);
    }
    // In the case of way of this writing, this is necessary.
    // And some_new_employee will be deleted when it will be out of scope
    delete temp_some_new_employee;
}
```

In the case of static object, it is deleted automatically.